# Jquery scroll : different execution in console/on page loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, razor

I'm in a partial, I have a scrollable div in which I have many messages (code is simplified)

```
<div class="panel-body y-scrollable" id="box-auto-resizable">
    <div id="message-list-auto-resizable">
        <ul class="chat-box">
            @foreach (var messagesGroup in this.Model.Messages)
            {
                <li class="text-center" style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0;">@messagesGroup.DisplaySendingDate</li>
                <li id="message-box-@this.Model.Id" class="message-box message-box-@( this.Model.IsCurrentUserSender ? "right" : "left") @(this.Model.IsHighlighted ? "message-highlighted" : "")" ></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on a result link, I wanted to load the thread and directly scroll to the message where the result is.
I wrote this script for this purpose :

```
function scrollToMessage(messageId) {
    if (messageId)
    {                           
        $("#box-auto-resizable").scrollTop(0).animate({ scrollTop: $("#message-box-" + messageId).position().top - $(".chat-box").position().top}, 300);
    }
}

if (@this.Model.ScrollToMessageId)
    scrollToMessage(@this.Model.ScrollToMessageId);
```

This function works perfectly when I call it from chrome's console. But not on the load of the "partial" (it's an ajax load. Code is below if needed).

Even crazier : I calculated the difference between a "local-scroll" and a "onLoad-scroll" for each message, and the offset between the two executions is non-continuous.
For example : for the 8 first messages there is no difference for the 2 executions, for the 4 following there is 80 pixels difference, then 170 then 190 for 5 other messages and I don't see any pattern.

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="setHeight();makeActive(@this.Model.Id, @this.Model.RfpId);return false;" data-ajax-update="#thread-message-list" href="/Message/ThreadMessageList?threadId=@this.Model.Id&messageId=@this.Model.MessageId" class="list-group-item text-right" id="message-@this.Model.MessageId">
@this.Model.ConversationName<br>
     <em>@Html.Raw(this.Model.Preview)</em>
</a>
```

**PS :** I just saw that I could identify the message to scroll to, by the class "message-highlighted" instead of ids, but it's not relevant for the bug, i'll change it later ;).

**EDIT :** I tested this with Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox, and it works. Chrome doesn't, Opera and Safari dunno...